# Is there a way to get Cassandra Role statistics?

Tags: authentication, cassandra

Authentication can be enabled on a Cassandra cluster using database roles. Recently, I landed into a situation where multiple roles were created for a Cassandra cluster running 3.11.x version, and I didn't have any easy way to figure out which role is actively used or not. Is there a way to get usage statistics of database roles in Cassandra 3.11.x versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that information is not stored locally.

The closest you can get to something like it is if you have [audit logging](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/auditlogging.html) enabled but it's a feature that was added in Apache Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-12151](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12151)) so it's not available in 3.11. Cheers!